# .NET Core 3.1 does not support File Download PDF or XLS or JPG through Swagger UI in Internet Explorer

Tags: file, download, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am migrating a .NET Core 2.1 API to .NET Core 3.1 and looks like the Produces File content is not supported. I am running into issue where the Swagger UI in Internet Explorer returns a Binary content as text instead of displaying it as PDF or XLS file.

In 2.1 I did the below to get it working:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/GetPdf")]
[Produces("application/pdf")]
public IActionResult GetPdf([FromBody]JObject data)
{
  FileContentResult fr = new FileContentResult(response.Documents.First().DocumentBytes, "application/pdf");
        fr.FileDownloadName = fileName;
  return fr;
 }
```

And added to Statup.cs Configure services:

```cs
c.MapType<FileStream>(() => new Schema { Type = "file", Format = "bytes[]" });
```

But this does not work in .NET Core 3.1. Could someone help on how to return PDF or XLS file via Swagger UI? I am using Swashbuckle ASP.NET Core 5.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, The above code did work, though it just does not in IE due to below:
Swagger UI does not support Internet Explorer. From the documentation:

Browser support

Swagger UI works in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4250 this solution looks as the posible solution for your problem

> Hi Team,
> Thanks for your quick suggestions by reproducing the issue.
> I also have tried by setting Content-Type: application/octet-stream and with Content-Disposition: attachment. The pdf link is enabled and it gets downloaded by clicking it.
> And thanks for confirming, Swagger-UI doesnot support inline viewing of PDF.

> Suggestions:
> If possible, please update the spec that "application/octet-stream" needs to used instead of "application/pdf".
> Spec Link : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/
> Under section : Response That Returns a File

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I tried this above mentioed post/solution , but it does not appear to work...             System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition       {    FileName = "text.pdf", Inline = false  // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline  };     System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType        {  MediaType = "application/octet-stream"}; Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());                    Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

Comment: But it converts the Content Type back to "application/PDF" on the browser, and the Swagger UI displays Response body


Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text.

Comment: then I think that is impossible to allow PDF download instantly, in that case the only way to test or prove that is using another tool or using an HttpClient that calls that request, swagger was thought to test json and xml endpoints.